# Serve the table

Tags: prepositions

How can I express my thought about serving the table AND setting something on it?
Is it right?

> I served the table **with** soup and pasta.

Comment: You serve your **guests** with soup and pasta, not the table.

Comment: I set the table with soup and pasta. 
I lay the table with soup and pasta. 
is it correct?

Also, is "The success of a party dinner in many aspects depends on capacity beautifully and correctly serve the table" correct?
If it is, then why can't I use it with a preposition?

Comment: You can set food **on** a table and you can set food **before** guests, but you cannot set a table **with** food, only with non-food items (cutlery, china, linen). I don't know why.

Comment: _I **set** the table with silverware and plates._   ...   ...    _I **serve** the guests (with) soup and pasta._  ("With" can be omitted in the second sentence.) We call a place at the table with a plate, silverware, glasses or cups, bowls, and so forth a _place setting._

Comment: _"The success of a party dinner in many aspects depends on capacity beautifully and correctly serve the table"_ includes too many errors to be addressed in comments, I'm afraid. We could rewrite it for you, but that would not help you or later users of our site.

Comment: ^ I just found it on the internet and thought it was right. No need to rewrite it )

Comment: LOL. Yes, I see it [**here.**](http://webuserblog.com/?p=5552) Obviously a _very_ bad translation from Ukrainian by using Google translate or a similarly useless tool. These tools don't work well from/to Slavic languages. "How to serve cutlery to the party table?" heehee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I served the table with soup and pasta.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence; it's correct grammatically.

A table also refers to the people sitting at it.  So the sentence implies that you served the people sitting at it with soup and pasta.  On the other hand, the phrase "set/lay the table" doesn't convey this sense.  It means to put a cloth, knives and forks, etc. in preparation for a meal.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically correct and its use is prevalent in the hospitality industry where a server may inform his colleagues or manager that he/she "served the table with soup and pasta"...and then took the order for desserts.